# composer issues when updating

Tags: composer-php, symfony-2.3

I've added "ornicar/apc-bundle": "1.0.*" to my composer.json in order to install it, but I'm getting this error:

```
 composer.phar update ornicar/apc-bundle

 Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

 Problem 1
   - Can only install one of: nelmio/alice[1.5.0, 1.6.x-dev].
   - Can only install one of: nelmio/alice[1.5.1, 1.6.x-dev].
   - Can only install one of: nelmio/alice[1.5.2, 1.6.x-dev].
   - Installation request for nelmio/alice == 1.6.9999999.9999999-dev -> satisfiable by nelmio/alice[1.6.x-dev].
   - Installation request for nelmio/alice 1.5.*@dev -> satisfiable by nelmio/alice[1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.5.2].
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem's been solved here.

https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/3198